# student's marks report

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me to write this code 
i want to display table like this 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/443/reportw.jpg/

Generated from three database tables depends on student ID

http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/1272/tablesh.jpg

So i want to display this table without any fixed value of exams or subjects .. i did it by this way and it is working good but i hope to know if it is the best way or not

```
 <? 


$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","123"); 
if (!$con) 
  { 
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
   } 
mysql_select_db("test", $con); 


//////////////////////// 



///////////////// Select the exams and put it in array  
$ex = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM exams");  
$dc=1; 
while ($rowex= mysql_fetch_array($ex)){ 
$exn[$dc]=$rowex['Exam_Title']; 
$exid[$dc]=$rowex['Exam_ID']; 
$dc++; 
} 


/////////////////////////// Select the subjects and put it in array  
$sj = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subjects");  
$dsj=1; 
while ($rowsj= mysql_fetch_array($sj)){ 
$sjn[$dsj]=$rowsj['Subj_Title']; 
$sjid[$dsj]=$rowsj['Subj_ID']; 
$dsj++; 
} 

////////////////Select the student marks and put it in array with subject id and exam id 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stu_marks");  
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
$arr[$row['Subj_ID']][$row['Exam_ID']]=$row['Grade']; 

} 
/////////////////////// count the exams and the subjects to draw the table 
 $exc=count($exn); 
 $sjc=count($sjn); 
 ?> 

 <table width="400" border="1"> 
  <tr> 



    <? 
///////// display subjects in table rows 
for ($d=0;$d<=$sjc;$d++){ 

if ($d==0){ 
    echo '<td>-</td>'; 
}else{ 
    echo ' <tr><td>'.$sjn[$d].'</td>'; 
} 

 ///////// display exams in table head tds  

for ($p=1;$p<=$exc;$p++){ 
if ($d==0){ 
    echo '<td> '.$exn[$p].'</td>'; 
}else{ 
?> 
 <td> 

 <?=$arr[$sjid[$d]][$exid[$p]]?> 

 </td> 
  <?} 
  } 
 }?> 

  </table>
```

i asking just if this is a good way to do this

sorry for my English language

Comment: What do you actually need help with? I don't see a specific question here.

Comment: What is the problem you're having? Is it PHP-related or do you need help with html-tables?

Comment: i asking just if this is a good way to do this.. ok i will ask in another place thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code works as is, and you just want to know if there is a better way, then [Code Review: Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better fit than here.

Comment: thank you .. i will try your suggestion